# DATEPART and DATEFIRST alternative for redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, datepart

I'm trying to run

```
SELECT DATEPART(week, date(date)), MIN(date)
```

in Redshift with the start day being Saturday. I tried using different syntax for `SET DATEFIRST` but it seems like it's not supported (or I just can't find the correct syntax for redshift). Are there any alternatives available?

The documentation page only shows information for extracting a specific dow (day of week): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_PART_function.html

Comment: It isn’t clear what result you are looking for.  Do you want the DOW with a different start day?  Or do you want the date of the start of the week?  Or something else?  You may be looking for DATE_TRUNC() function but I’m not sure.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I want to group data of a long period (e.g. a year) into weeks. The starting date of each week should be Saturday.

Comment: So yes, you want date_trunc().  I’ll write something up for you …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date_trunc() function will truncate a timestamp to any number of levels including “week”.  If memory serves a date_trunc to a week will set the result to midnight of the Monday before the given timestamp.

Now you want it to truncate to Saturday, 2 days earlier, and this is doable by adding 2 days before the date_trunc and then subtracting 2 days after.  Like this (untested so forgive any typos):

```
date_trunc(‘week’, <your-timestamp> + interval ‘2 days’) - interval ‘2 days’
```